# Laravel installer installation failed

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

When I try this to install Laravel:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

i will get this error:

```
Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap     configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details
```

I guess i fixed it with these commands. I this the right way? Does anyone knows?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=512k
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

I'm using Digitalocean and using 512 MB / 20 GB Disk / Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

Answer (score 0):

Rather `global require` use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project`

or create a `composer.json` file. put the content in it, then run `composer install` because `composer install` takes less memory then `composer update`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Or should I just use a 1gb droplet?